# How to iterate over numerically named object properties in defined order?

Tags: javascript

In theory, the order of iteration over object properties is not guaranteed. 
In practice, there is a de-facto standard about it.
IE<9, Firefox, Safari always iterate in the order of definition.
Opera, IE9, Chrome iterate in the order of definition for string keys.
Numeric keys become sorted and go before string keys.

I have an object-filled array, the all keys are numbers. How can I iterate over those object properties in defined order. In ie9 and chrome, the numeric keys are always sorted before iteration.

Comment: But the key of the array in object, how can I get an object key from an array. I tried  for (key in ary) {
        document.write(ary[key]+"<br>");

    }
The result is like [object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]   Is there any good way to get the key?

Comment: I provided sample code in my answer below.

Comment: I just used console.log() to trace back the result and found what I need is actually sort the array by the second property of an object in an object-filled array. For example, in the page source code the element in the array like [61230,'61230','Apple','YES'],
[42689,'42689','Banana','YES'],
[52668,'52668','Orange, Julian','YES']   I want to sort by the name 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange' in alphabetical order. In FF and ie<9, they are, but in chrome and ie9, this array are sorted by the numbers, which means the result are printed out like 'Banana', 'Orange' and 'Apple'.How to get the right order

Comment: Your latest comment has nothing to do with your original question.  What you've shown here is an array of arrays.  Are you saying you want to sort the outer array by the 3rd element in the inner arrays?

Comment: I added a new sort option to my answer based on your latest comment.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do this in any guaranteed fashion is to get all the keys into an array, sort the array and then iterate using the array.

Here's some pseudo code:

```
var obj = {};  // object with lots of properties
var keys = [];
for (var i in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        keys.push(i);
    }
}

// may have to craft a custom sort function to get the right order
keys.sort();
for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    // operate on obj[keys[i]]
}
```

---

**EDIT:** based on a new comment, it now sounds like the OP wants to sort an array of arrays using the 3rd element in the inner array as the sort key.  So, if you have:

```
[[52668,'52668','Orange, Julian','YES'], [61230,'61230','Apple','YES'], [42689,'42689','Banana','YES']]
```

he wants to sort by the fruit name (the 3rd item in the inner array)

This can be done like this:

```
var data = [[52668,'52668','Orange, Julian','YES'], [61230,'61230','Apple','YES'], [42689,'42689','Banana','YES']];

data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return(a[2].localeCompare(b[2]));
});
```